# non-global npm install slow or stalls when ran on IIS, but global installs and local machine installs are quick

Tags: npm, iis, nuxt.js, npm-install

When installing production dependencies (nuxt, express) on an IIS server, `npm install` is either extremely slow, or at times completely stalls.

When these packages are installed globally on IIS (`npm install -g`), the installation is quick and works well.

When these packages are installed globally ***or*** locally on my local machine, the installation is quick and works well. This leads me to believe possibly not an npm problem.

I have tried different npm versions, configs - registries, proxies, etc. The connection to the registry seems fine.

Has anyone experiences this or can think of any solutions? I am new to IIS and all help is appreciated.

**Update**

Small packages with no dependencies are downloaded easily, while large packages stall.

Comment: You can try to reset  registry: npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/. Your connection may have some issues with npm https connection.

Comment: Hey Bruce,

Thanks for the reply.

I've tried with different registry url configs to no avail.

Comment: Problem was server permissions related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was server permissions

Comment: What specific permissions did you need to set? Where?

Comment: I had to log in using Microsoft Remote Desktop and it worked. Connecting through Volume Mount led to these limitations. It was possibly just speed related. I don't know what sets that and didn't have the time/resources to dive any deeper. @JeremyCaney

Open to any insight

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Installs stalled. Searching npm from the cli was sloooow.

Turned out to be an ipv6 issue. To work around it,

1. disable ipv6 on your machine
2. use npm
3. re-enable ipv6 on your machine

Quick google search will show you how depending on your OS.